# How can I bind a JBoss AS 6 running as service to 0.0.0.0?

Tags: java, windows, service, jboss, jboss6.x

Where in the JBoss AS 6 startup script can I set the -b 0.0.0.0 parameter like in JBoss AS 5? The new version reads input from a temporary file .r.lock

```
:cmdStart
REM Executed on service start
del .r.lock 2>&1 | findstr /C:"being used" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
  echo Could not continue. Locking file already in use.
  goto cmdEnd
)
echo Y > .r.lock
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Starting %SVCDISP%" > run.log
call run.bat < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1
jbosssvc.exe -p 1 "Shutdown %SVCDISP% service" >> run.log
del .r.lock
goto cmdEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you should modify these line:

```
call run.bat < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1
```

for something like that:

```
call run.bat -b 0.0.0.0 < .r.lock >> run.log 2>&1
```

You can read more in JBoss Docs (its for JBoss EAP 5.1 but I think it should be similar): [Run the Application Server as a Service](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/5/html/Installation_Guide/run_application_server_as_a_service.html).