# How can I specify run.bat options when running JBoss as a service?

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

In Windows Server 2008 R2, I can run JBoss successfully from the command line specifying options suchs as  "-b 0.0.0.0". However, I want to run JBoss as a Windows service. I understand that I run /Path/To/JBoss/bin/service.bat install from the command line and this basically runs the start.bat whenever the computer starts. How do I configure the service to start with the command line arguments of -b 0.0.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [How can I bind a JBoss AS 6 running as service to 0.0.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171875/how-can-i-bind-a-jboss-as-6-running-as-service-to-0-0-0-0?rq=1)

You could just hardcode `-b 0.0.0.0` inside `run.bat`.

BTW, consider using [Java Service Wrapper](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-overview.html) or [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) as [RunJBossAsAServiceOnWindows wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RunJBossAsAServiceOnWindows) suggests. It allows to specify various service params in config.